# touchscreen ft5x06 not responding?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, device-tree, imx6

I am using kontron smarc-samx6i board run with nxp imx6q processor. I am currently working with yocto In that I need to interface a touch screen of ft5316 through I2C . For that I edited the device tree as follows:

```
polytouch: edt_ft5x06@39 {
         compatible = "edt","edt_ft5x06","edt-ft5x06";
         reg = <0x39>;
         pinctrl-names = "default";
         pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_smx6_i2c_gpio_1>;
         irq_pin=<&gpio3 1 0>;
         interrupt-parent = <&gpio3>;
         interrupts = <0 70 0x04>;
};
```

When I am using `i2cdump` command the touchscreen responds successfully, but when I am working with module it won't respond.

When I am using the below command i am getting following output

```
root@smarc-samx6i:~# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0100

N: Name="gpio-keys.27"

P: Phys=gpio-keys/input0

S: Sysfs=/devices/soc0/gpio-keys.27/input/input0

U: Uniq=

H: Handlers=kbd event0 evbug

B: PROP=0

B: EV=23

B: KEY=4000 100000 0 0 0

B: SW=1
```

My device did not probe and i am not getting any error while instantiating the device using the command:

```
echo edt_ft5x06 0x39> /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device
Instantiated device edt_ft5x06 at 0x39 device
```

How can i make it work!!

Comment: When you edited your device tree, did you update/rebuild your initramfs? If you didn't, then it won't be able to load on boot but will allow for manual registering once logged in which seems to be the issue you're having.

Comment: When I modify the device tree I am using the two commands such as **bitbake linux-smx6 -f -c compile** and **bitbake linux-smx6** for each and every time.

Comment: Can you provide the BitBake recipe so we can see what it does? Just from a hunch through, run `update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)`. This assumes there's a hook written to add all device tree binaries to the initramfs which there should be.

Comment: i am using core-image-sato and The command you provided where should i use it?

Comment: run it at the standard terminal prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "when working with the module it won't respond" you mean it won't respond to any touch events on the touchscreen. Did the driver module correctly load? Is it built-in or used as a loadable module? Did you check "dmesg" for confirming the driver loaded properly or output of lsmod? If the driver loaded properly, are you getting interrupts?

What is the output of "cat /proc/interrupts"? Do you see the interrupt requests increasing when you press the touchscreen? If not then, then you have a problem with interrupts. If you see the interrupts, can you check with an utility like "evtest" to see if you get touchscreen events?

Comment: yes i agree with that the module won't respond to any touch event. And the module is comming as loadable and it is not a built in module.But we the yocto it self gives us a module for this particular touchscreen. When i load this module no error is showing and the lsmod command shows that the module is inserted but interrupt for touchscreen is not listed in /proc/interrupts file..

Comment: While lsmod can show the driver module as loaded but it does not necessarily imply that the driver's probe function got called which must be called and succeed for the driver to work. I also see that you use the address 0x39. Are you sure that's correct? I believe it should be 0x38. Also I am not sure but I have seen atleast two FT5316 based touchscreen which used 1.8V logic. May be that should be taken care of properly.

Comment: When i check the **i2cdetect** command shows the device address is **0x39** thats why i give that value and also i verified using **i2cget** command that where i am getting the data of right device it is also fine. and also we take care of that 1.8V logic.

Comment: Ok then, You should put some prints in the probe function and check if it succeeds.

Comment: I just modified the device driver to get data from DTB but now i am getting a new problem on issuing irq as **genirq: Setting trigger mode 6 for irq 224 failed (gpio_set_irq_type+0x0/0x238)** What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Hmm..I am not sure...It seems it could not set trigger type for IRQ on concerned GPIO. What kernel version you got on the module? Is the edt driver patched up correctly for DT? Did you check by putting prints in the driver and checking if it takes the correct data from the dt?

Comment: its already given by the distributor. and the DT is modified by my self. And about the print i think the device is not probed by the driver as well. I just made a **printk** inside the driver program it won't print at all.